# why do i get scroll bars when using google line chart?

Tags: google-api, linechart

I am using [google line chart api](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) and no matter how big i make the div chart dimentions, it always shows a horizontal and vertical scroll bar.  how can i stop this from happening.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the HTML, JavaScript and CSS being use to render the chart? Or a simplified example that has the same behavior? Does this happen in different browsers?

Comment: you should have so posted your code; would help massively on your question :) Also as Christian mentioned: does this happen on all browsers or so?

Comment: @leora: are you sure that scrollbars are not applied by the parent element that actually contains the chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CONTEXT: editable HTML of https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart  (using Firefox or Chorme).

Instructions for help you in the problem:

- suppose you need a box with width=500px  and height=400px.
- check Javascript at new google.visualization.LineChart(), if the width and height inicializations are 500 and 400.
- check if style of the HTML tag (perhaps div) of renderization place (id="visualization") is style="width: 800px; height: 400px;".
- check if style of the HTML parent tag (any) of renderization place is bigger than 500 and 400, or is 100%.

Another solution is by "HTML cut": use overflow:hidden.

**EXAMPLE OF CASE WITH SCROLL**

```js
        // ... piece of your javacascript.
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                    width: 800, height: 400,
                    vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
            );
    } google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

```html
<!-- ... piece of your HTML -->
<div id="container" style="width:400px;overflow:scroll;">
  <div id="visualization" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
```

**HTML SOLUTION (fix the container width)**

```
<!-- ... piece of your HTML -->
<div id="container" style="width:800px;overflow:scroll;">
  <div id="visualization" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
```

**ANOTHER SIMPLE HTML SOLUTION (use overflow:hidden)**

```
<!-- ... piece of your HTML -->
<div id="container" style="width:400px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div id="visualization" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
```

... or reduce all, Javascript and HTML widths and heights, etc.

Comment: thanks  . .looked like i had some extra css that was changing the overflow

Answer (score 1):

Using :

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
//init your data
var options = {
      width: "100%", height: "100%",
      //other options

}
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
</script>
....

<body>
   <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```

You ensure that the graph will fit the div you're using.

Then to resize the graph set `style="width: ...px; height: ...px;"` with the desired size :

```
<body>
  <div style="width: 800px; height: 400px;" id="chart"></div>
</body>
```